# Utilize Python Input() to perform DateShift on a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, input

I have a dataset where, whenever a date value in the `Update` column is entered into the input() prompt, **Date1, Date2** and **Date3**
values will be updated according to these rules:

```
   Date1 is 5 months from the date entered in the input() prompt
   Date2 is 2 months from the date entered in the input() prompt
   Date3 is 1 month from the date entered in the input() prompt
```

**The only data that is changing are the **dates**, which are essentially getting shifted based upon the user input.**

**Data**

```
ID   Stat   Date1     Date2     Date3       Update
aa   500    1/1/2021  4/1/2021  5/1/2021    6/1/2021
bb   800    1/1/2021  4/1/2021  5/1/2021    6/1/2021
```

**Desired**

Input prompt will ask user which date value they wish to input.
**User inputs the date '8/1/2021'**, **which updates the remaining column date values.** based on rules above.

```
ID   Stat   Date1     Date2     Date3       Update
aa   500    3/1/2021   6/1/2021 7/1/2021    8/1/2021
bb   800    3/1/2021   6/1/2021 7/1/2021    8/1/2021
```

**Doing**

I believe I can use a combination of a function as well as user prompt to approach this problem.

*Type input*

```
datevalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter date value: "))
print(datevalue)
```

*Use input variable in function or script to create date update for Date1, Date2 and Date3*

```
df[0] = df[1].apply(lambda x: datevalue - pd.DateOffset(months=x))

s = df['Update'].str.replace(r'(\S+) (\S+)', r'\2\1')
df['Update'] = (pd.PeriodIndex(s, freq='D') + 3).strftime('D%q %Y')
```

I am looking for **some starting point suggestion or a good foundation/documentation** on how to best approach this problem. I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: So, for e.g., since the user input is 2 months greater than `Update`, add 2 months to all dates?

Comment: Hi @user17242583 all dates are updated from the  value in the 'Update' column
Date 1 is 5 months from the Update column value
Date 2 is 2 months from the Update column value
Date 3 is 1 month from the Update column value

Comment: When you say "Date 1 is 5 months from the Update column value" do you mean "Date 1 **_should be_** 5 months from the Update column value", i.e., that's what you _want_ it to be?

Comment: yes it is what I am wanting it to be. Lets say user enters a new date of 10/1/2021 in the update column. I now want Date1, Date2 and Date3 to be updated based on that input.

Comment: And by "updated" you mean you want the difference between old update and new update to be added to all the dates, right? If so, see my answer below.

Comment: no not the difference. The new dates are being updated based on what the user inputs,  as well as the defined rules @user17242583

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define a mapping dictionary which maps the column names to corresponding dateoffset, then create a series from this dictionary and subtract the `datevalue` from offsets, finally `assign` the updated date values back to dataframe

```
d = {
    'Date1': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
    'Date2': pd.DateOffset(months=2),
    'Date3': pd.DateOffset(months=1),
}

s = pd.Series(d).rsub(datevalue)
df.assign(**{**s, 'Update': datevalue})
```

---

```
   ID  Stat      Date1      Date2      Date3     Update
0  aa   500 2021-03-01 2021-06-01 2021-07-01 2021-08-01
1  bb   800 2021-03-01 2021-06-01 2021-07-01 2021-08-01
```

Comment: Thank you - what does the ‘**’ symbolize? @shubham

Comment: It expands a `dict` object into something else, @Lynn. For the first `**`, it expands the keys/values of the dict as keyword args.

Comment: @shubham, I wonder if you could respond to my latest post? thank you

Comment: @Lynn Sure, I'll try to answer.

Comment: Ok yes I am trying to incorporate the conditional -still researching thank you kindly

Comment: Great! Can you ping me the link to the latest question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
cols = df.filter(like='Date').columns.tolist() + ['Update']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col) + (datevalue - df['Update']))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID  Stat      Date1      Date2      Date3     Update
0  aa   500 2021-03-03 2021-06-01 2021-07-01 2021-08-01
1  bb   800 2021-03-03 2021-06-01 2021-07-01 2021-08-01
```